# Error 400 (Bad Request) when get a file which name contains & character in C# ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an issue regarding the filename which contains `&` character.

I have to get an image which name is: `Test&TestAgain.jpg`. In ASP.NET MVC3 application, in View side, I put

```
Url.Content( "~/Content/Images/"+ filename );
```

In Chrome, I see error **400 Bad Request** because of filename which contains `&`.

I think that `&` is used for query string and browser interprets file name as query string.

Because filename doesn't contain `?` then browser throw that error. (**A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).**)

It is a way (workaround) to fix this without replace that character ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/SV-SE/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode.aspx) the path:

```
Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(filename));
```

**Edit:**

Seems it doesn't work. The only way I can think of right now is to allow [resticted characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129) and enable [VerificationCompatibility](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;826437) by setting in the registry:

```
// 32-bit IIS
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET VerificationCompatibility = 1

// 64-bit IIS
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET VerificationCompatibility = 1
```

Comment: Nope, it is not working...I tried many times. No success. Browser will interprets that `&` anyway